# How can we get the boss to stop using an anecdote during pitches that makes us look incompetent?

Tags: management

I work for a startup where we have to frequently pitch to customers and investors. I'm the most senior developer in experience, but I did not want the lead role, so I could avoid most client meetings as I hate dealing with insane requests. My boss still brings me along anyway.

During pitches, they talk about how we are proactive about security because we know that users won't be. They then go into this story about how they "used [their] hashtable skills to create a frequency table of passwords and none of them looked very secure. "First of all, any decent junior developer can do a hashmap, so it is not the awesome skill they think it is and second, nobody should be able to see the passwords at all as passwords must be hashed and salted. I implemented that when I arrived, so the "password hashmap" can't be done anymore, but she keeps pretending like it was something done recently.

She has another anecdote about how "the software used to have a feature where our clients could just use SQL to do their data analysis, but security people (me) made them get rid of it." We developers call it SQL injection.

We are a startup that stores medical data and the CTO goes on about "world class security" (which we don't have, but I digress), so it alarms every technical person we pitch. You can visibly see the alarm in the eyes of the technical people. I have learned to stand in the back and mouth "I did not do that. I did not do that." The worst case was when one investor came to my LinkedIn a day later to yell at me for "trying to scam him with something out of PHP for Dummies."

Not one pitch has succeeded when she has used the anecdote and I have to deal with potential clients and investors asking me how the heck we can be so careless with medical data.

My boss doesn't believe that not hashing passwords is a serious issue that would cause investors to skip a company.

I've told my boss to stop as knowing user passwords indicates that our security is not anywhere near world class and she says the story "makes us seem scrappy and homey." Normally I would just leave it be as we have sufficient contracts to keep my job so further growth is not my problem, but I'm concerned for my own reputation.

Can you think of any other way to get my boss to stop this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108033/discussion-on-question-by-belflunder-how-to-get-boss-to-stop-using-an-anecdote-d).

Comment: You mouthing "I did not do that" during a sales meeting sounds horrible to me. Could you tell what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 147):

You're the most senior developer, time to act like it. To stop playing charades in a meeting would be a good start.

If your boss is bringing you along, you need to bring your expertise to the table.

I can't believe how lucky you are that you have feedback from potential clients and investors. That should have been given to your boss as you received it. In any case, it's now time to compile a report containing ALL feedback you've received, along with your summary of where you think the issues lie. Present it to your boss.

I disagree with other answers that you need to find other anecdote. Good security means you shouldn't have stories to tell, it's that simple. You should be discussing security features. You should be discussing how you validate compliance. You should be discussing why you don't have any stories to tell.

If you can't convince your boss, with all due respect, your company doesn't deserve new clients. And the company probably doesn't deserve you. What do you think it going to happen when you uncover a large security flaw somewhere? Do you think your boss is going to trust your assessment and ensure it gets fixed. I don't think they would.

Comment: OP admits that they don't actually have world class security, so these stories may be all they have.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser Probably all the more reason to not talk about it then!

Comment: This is the right answer. Right or wrong, the boss is paid the big bucks to make these decisions. If they cannot be convinced to make different decisions, that's on them. Either maneuver yourself into a position of greater responsibility where you can make the company look better, or find a new company, or put up with it. I completely understand the OP's concern about their own personal reputation but unfortunately that's the nature of working in a team. Basically, life's not fair. :(

Comment: "What do you think it going to happen when you uncover a large security flaw somewhere?" -- Oh, let me take a stab at that one! The boss will blame the OP for not doing the job perfectly. This boss sounds like the type who wants credit for others' successes but isn't willing to stay invested in understanding those successes.

Comment: And yeah, mouthing anything in a meeting to contradict your boss is bad. Please stop that @Bellfunder. It won't help you look better to the audience.

Follow up afterward (without airing dirty laundry) if you need to correct a major error of fact.

Comment: +1 Great answer about how as an engineer / developer technical knowledge is his strength. Relying on hard technical facts and providing ideas on how to validate security compliance is great advice!

Comment: An anecdote is not necessarily a story about a quick hack to fix a problem that shouldn't have happened. It could be how you were grilled by X and they couldn't fault you, how Z contacted you to teach students about your compliance processes, how you dropped a vendor because you revealed vulnerabilities they had and weren't addressing properly, or how you won a contract because you had superior security. The list is endless. It remains true that in sales/pitch situations humans react much more strongly to storytelling than a dry exposé.

Comment: Claiming that you have “world class security” is just something that makes people cringe.

Comment: @gnasher729 Absolutely agree! Far better to say "we comply with ISO XYZ and EU standard FOO" in an offhand way. Rather than making a large song and dance about it.

Answer (score 133):

> Not one pitch has succeeded when she has used the anecdote and I have
>   to deal with potential clients and investors asking me how the heck we
>   can be so careless with medical data.
>
> Can you think of any other way to get my boss to stop this?

Compile some of the specific feedback you have received from potential clients and investors. Quote them exactly. Don't paraphrase.

Present these to your boss and indicate "This is why we should change our pitch".

Comment: The OP doesn't say how often this happen, so to compile a collection may take a while. IMO even one should be enough, and then repeat each time it happens.

Comment: They *did* say they specifically got an angry LinkedIn response - that alone is proof that they aren't coming off as 'scrappy', but rather' incompetent'.

Comment: @Zibbobz It's not technically "proof" but it is good prima facie evidence. Does the boss have one shred of empirical evidence, not just her own gut, that this is coming off well? If not, she needs to hush or at least be more strategic.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive I'd probably say that if the assertion was that clients are getting put off by certain behaviour, and then the client outright says they were put off by that behaviour, that's probably as close to proof as you're ever going to get.

Comment: If I lose three deals, that’s enough. You don’t want to wait until you lose a dozen deals.

Comment: The fact that she lost several deals when telling the anecdote plus a statement from their lead developer is prima facile evidence where any person with any business sense would change what they are doing. The feedback from that lost customer is damning evidence.

Comment: @Gregory Currie Think about outliers. There's *some* chance the client who said this is six standard deviations more ornery than the average client. (Not likely, especially given all the other evidence presented here!) Taken alone, it's rare that a sample size of one is proof of anything useful beyond that individual. Here we don't have to take it alone, because we have other evidence this boss is clueless.

Answer (score 56):

"Scrappy and homey" is a good thing for a mom-and-pop store.. It is a very bad thing for a company required by law to have due diligence.

Make it simpler for her. This isn't that you have a difference of opinion on how good the story is. This is her telling potential customers about a time she broke the law. Under GDPR in the EU, both those stories indicate the company or a company employee committing an actual crime, for which she personally would be likely to be fined and barred from being a company director for some period.

What you're describing is literally criminal incompetence, because your company broke the law and the people in the company then were too dumb to know they were breaking the law. Not only that, if you're the senior developer then she is implying to potential customers that you are the one who's criminally incompetent. You should take a very fun view of this.

You say this is a startup. That probably means there aren't many people. I suggest you gather them all together, and tell them this in your position as the senior developer. Tell them all they're lucky they haven't yet been found out for what they did with people's data before, and they must never *ever* reveal this in future or every one of their careers personally could be ended by it, and the company certainly would be.

Comment: You are exaggerating. Security risks are not a crime until an actual data leak occurs and incompetence is proven.

Comment: Data leaks happen daily. Think what will happen if they have an incident (e.g. a ransomware infection), and one of it customers mentions "last week they mentioned they stored passwords in plaintext"

Comment: @jacques - not entirely correct. There are often regulatory frameworks/requirements that would make these risks criminal violations even without a data breach.

Comment: @Jacques Certainly under GDPR in the EU, you are not correct.  Exposing private information such as healthcare data in a way that other people can access without the person's permission is a crime in its own right, separate from the crime of actually accessing that data without the person's permission.  In fact this is the pretty much the entire purpose of GDPR, to make a company responsible for its failures *before* people actually have their person data stolen.  In driving terms, it's like being able to arrest someone for driving dangerously *before* they actually kill someone.

Comment: @Jacques ... And whilst GDPR is not universal, it is being widely adopted round the world.  For starters, it's best practise anyway.  But to hit the company in their pockets, if they aren't compliant with GDPR then they can't do business with any European company or person.  For a global industry like healthcare, no customer will ever do business with you.

Comment: @Graham OP never mentioned actual data leaks happening, only that there existed the possibility of data leaks through bad security. You would be right when the company actually leaked data while the OP only mentioned that security risks existed (which are now closed). In your metaphor it's more like arresting someone for being a bad driver while they're sitting at home.

Comment: @Jacques especially for medical data, there are almost certainly regulations about how it's stored, regardless of whether there's a known leak or not. It's completely possible they've already had a leak and just don't know it, too.

Comment: Anyone that says "it's not a crime to insecurely handle medical data unless there's an actual breach and they prove incompetence" is someone that doesn't work with medical data.  As someone who works with medical claims data, I can guarantee you: you can absolutely get fined up the wazoo even if there's no actual breach, let alone getting "proven incompetent."  I can't imagine the boggled look an external auditor would have if you told them, "Oh, we don't hash our passwords.  But it's okay - we haven't had a breach, so we're not in violation of any HIPAA laws."

Comment: @Jacques Read my previous comment. Creating the *possibility* of a data leak is a crime in its own right. Unless you've reduced that possibility to as low as reasonably practicable, you're committing a crime. If you haven't understood that, you haven't understood GDPR, and you certainly haven't had any involvement with any form of data security.

Comment: Jaques, it might be exaggerating, that’s fine as long as it stops her. You don’t admit to a crime. But you also don’t admit to something where people seriously discuss if it’s a crime. Say you talk to customer and three underlings. And the third underling says to his boss (the customer) “I think she just admitted a crime”. That’s very very bad even if the third underling is technically wrong.

Answer (score 17):

Your best shot here is to come up with better stories for your boss to tell. She's not going to stop telling these stories on her own. I suggest you focus on making moves that improve the security of your app and make it easier for your clients to use it securely. Every time you make an improvement, brag about it to your boss. Word these updates in a way that will 1) impress her enough to repeat it and 2) make your company look smart when she repeats it. Eventually, you may find that she starts using these new, good stories instead of her old, bad ones.

Comment: Make new anecdotes, and make em stick.

Comment: I'm rather skeptical of this advice. The situation sounds like a dumb thing that gets stuck in a dumb person's mind. Dumb -- but simple, memorable, and a unique story because no one else goes around saying the same thing. To a crude storyteller, that's gold. Moreover the fact that OP has pushed back against it will actually make it even more memorable (see: [backfire effect](https://daily.jstor.org/the-backfire-effect/)). The advice here seems like a very faint hope. Do you have experience of this tactic working?

Comment: No, Not really. I think voting on this question has put the answers in roughly the correct order here, though. So I feel ok leaving this one up.

Answer (score 5):

**Does your boss understand the technical side at all?**

From the hashmap example and the casual acceptance of the SQL query form, I am guessing that your boss doesn't actually have a strong technical background. There is no competitive advantage to not hashing passwords from the beginning. Most frameworks build it in from the start.

**The only reason for it ever to have been true is that your boss did not know it needed to be done.**

I was part of a startup accelerator where tons of people learned to code to launch their startups. The code quality was terrible. The approaches were comical. But because the Udemy tutorials told them to hash their passwords, they did it. All but one company there had hashed passwords. Few knew why they were doing it, but they knew the best practice was to do so. Your boss probably never took that approach.

Same with the SQL form. Did your boss appreciate the power of SQL? I had to show this to a founder who had a similar thing. To them, SQL was nothing more than `insert` and `select`. They had never heard of `drop` and were quite alarmed when they found what it did.

"Password hashing" might just be technobabble to your boss. Does she understand that doing it prevents a hacker from logging into user accounts if the database is compromised? I would bet she doesn't.

**Try explaining the consequences of not having these things.**

Plain passwords == easy hacking.

SQL injection == some bad person can come and delete the database or steal all the information in the database.

Comment: While I agree that, judging by OP's descriptions, OP's boss doesn't understand the technical details, she _does_ appear to understand that they were (somehow) bad for security, which is why she's bragging that these issues were fixed. What she fails to realize is how _basic_ these fixes were. It's like bragging about recently having started to lock your door to keep out intruders. (No idea how to explain that tactfully, though...)

Comment: With regards to SQL injection, forget "bad person".  The real threat is a *careless* person who forgets the "where" clause on their `update` statement.

Comment: +1 As a developer, technical knowledge is his strength and he should leverage that to the maximum ability

Comment: @Llewellyn those don't seem to be bragging about the issues being fixed. With the password frequency table, she is talking about addressing one security issue ( a human one) in a way that causes another (a technical one).  The 2nd one is just her being irritated at a feature being removed.

Comment: “We recently started locking our doors, so now we have world class security”. Potential customer thinks “what a bunch of clueless bozos”.

Comment: Hashed passwords = incompetent. Salted+hashed passwords Ok. Don’t tell her. I wouldn’t want to know what she would turn that into.

Answer (score 2):

If your boss is the company owner, tell her about the feedback you received, like the one saying you were trying to scam them. Tell her that she is telling anecdotes showing total incompetence. If she is not the company owner, tell whoever is above her that she kills sales.

Or you can pray that she pitches to a client who doesn’t just quietly go away with a sale lost, but tells her exactly why she lost the sale.

Comment: I'm concerned that the OP's boss is one of these "you can't tell me what to do, I'll do just the opposite to show you who's boss" type people (e.g., [backfire effect](https://daily.jstor.org/the-backfire-effect/)).

Comment: In that case, we’ll have another startup turning into a failed startup.

Answer (score 2):

> ......so I could avoid most client meetings as I hate dealing with insane requests

You agree that the clients’ requests are absurd which means they are not technical.

Your CEO is also a non-technical person and uses technical terms or technologies to impress those above mentioned clients.

So let’s be honest here:

As long as you are dealing with these types of clients, you are fine. Try to learn how to deal with these clients instead of avoiding them.

However, if I were you I would have suggested my CEO to ask me to explain tech when it comes to technical stuff. Tell her: “This will sound more professional and I would be able to impress them more.”

Comment: This.  The boss is there for the overarching leadership, and should be passing the purely technical points over to OP.  That gives some credulence and reason for being at the meetings.  It demonstrates Team and delegation.

Comment: @Criggie exactly

Comment: But the OP said *"... I did not want the lead role, so I could avoid most client meetings as I hate dealing with insane requests"*.

Answer (score 0):

If your boss has to resort to anecdotes it probably means that they are not confident and do not know the details of your work or how to handle the situation effectively. Hence, they are trying to act in a situation which they find difficult themselves. My advice: change team if this is leading you feeling angry/frustrated. Changing another person is much more difficult than finding another job!

Comment: There’s absolutely nothing wrong with anecdotes, and it’s probably the #1 tool in a salesperson’s repertoire. There’s something wrong with *these specific* anecdotes.

Comment: I think it's important how anecdotes see used. They can be part of good mentorship but the tone and situation are likely to determine their success

Comment: Yes Kondrad I do think that anecdotes can be used in a constructive or destructive way depending on the intent.

Answer (score 0):

You are there for your technical expertise so start saying it - the next time the boss launches into one of those anecdotes you reply to it "obviously not salting passwords was terrible, that's why those guys aren't here now and I am".  Use it as an opportunity to show how things have developed.  The boss gets to keep telling the story but you mitigate the impact. Hopefully the boss will learn from the reaction you get!

Comment: So your suggestion is to contradict the boss during the meeting with the client?

Comment: Not contradict no, but finish the story, turn it around and make it about an improvement.

Comment: But how do you mean? The boss tells the story and then you interrupt and say "no, obviously not salting was terrible"? Or how?

Comment: You waitit ill they finish their story then you add your comments, I don't see what's so difficult about this. What are you doing there if you're not going to interject or answer technical questions?

Comment: Can you make clearer how this conversation should go? And I do think you are here to answer technical questions from the client, but I can't see howreplying "obviously not salting was terrible" can be said without contradicting the boss?